# Getting timeout error on updating the record in oracle c#

Tags: c#, oracle11g, enterprise-library

while updating a record in particular table getting timeout error. But I am able to insert the record in the same table.

Insert, Update happening in the DBTransaction . Able to update the same record via Toad.

Using Enterprise Data Library for Data Access component.

how to identify the route cause to this issue. please advise.

Comment: Can you show us the code please?

Comment: i checked in the mornings. surprise it works now. i didn't change any code nothing. but still i looking for reason for this cause.

Comment: What is the exact Oracle error number ( ORA- )?